# Detect which apps are opened in Android

Tags: java, android, oop, logcat

I'm attempting to build a service which will show a toast to the user when the user launches any app within Android.

Everywhere I look, I see people suggesting the use of logcat to track the starting of apps - so I decided that's the proper method.

Additionally, the method that's posted is as follows:

```
try
{
Process mLogcatProc = null;
BufferedReader reader = null;
mLogcatProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"logcat", "-d"});

reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mLogcatProc.getInputStream()));

String line;
final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator"); 

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    log.append(line);
    log.append(separator);
}
String w = log.toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),w, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

catch (Exception e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

However, this doesn't really explain how to detect the opening of a specific package or application.

So, my question is this:

How do I scan the activity log of android programmatically from my service to detect which packages are started.

Thus, the output should be dumped to an array with only the package names of the apps that have been opened!

Comment: "Everywhere I look, I see people suggesting the use of logcat to track the starting of apps - so I decided that's the proper method" -- [that approach has been defunct since Android 4.1](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/12/read-logs-regression.html), except probably on rooted devices.

Comment: It has been? So what's the proper method for Android 4.1+?

Comment: There really isn't one. I'm sure some people poll on `ActivityManager` results, but that'll be battery-intensive for any accuracy, and it probably won't work on Android 5.0+ either, given changes to `ActivityManager`.

Comment: Why is it then, that the apps on the app store that have been update recently like App Lock still contain the permission "Read sensitive log data" which I assume is invoked by the permission <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>?

Comment: I would imagine that it is to support older devices where they *can* read the logs. For example, if polling `ActivityManager` drains the battery worse than reading the logs, I'd want to read the logs where I can, falling back to something else where I can't.

Comment: I see, thanks for the pointer! I'll see what I can do from here!